# How to run my local angular project by using globally installed npm packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I want to do something like this, where, I want to keep all my packages globally just like node package itself. So for example in my package.json I have a package name called "Highcharts" I want to install it globally I don't want to create a local node_modules folder and use it but I want to access it from outside  so next time whenever I want to create a copy of my project folder I should be able to use highcharts directly without using npm install. Is it possible?

globally installed node_modules - > **Users/user/AppData/Roaming/node_modules/highcharts**

app

- src
- node_modules (I don't want to keep it)
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- angular.json

How to link these globally installed node_modules with the current app or any app which we want to create?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- local packages are installed in the project directory
- global packages are installed in a single place in your system

Usually it is a good idea to have all npm packages required for your project installed locally (project folder). This makes sure, that you can have dozens of applications which are running a different versions of each package if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Marek. I want to have only one version as of now but globally so next time when I want to create a new app I should just need to do ng serve and it should be able to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

`export NODE_PATH='yourdir'/node_modules`

Hello, if am getting right, you want to keep all dependencies global.
You can just run install with -g command. Those libraries will be available in node installation folder.

#### From the Node docs

If the NODE_PATH environment variable is set to a colon-delimited list of absolute paths, then node will search those paths for modules if they are not found elsewhere. (Note: On Windows, NODE_PATH is delimited by semicolons instead of colons.)

Additionally, node will search in the following locations:

1: $HOME/.node_modules

2: $HOME/.node_libraries

3: $PREFIX/lib/node

Where $HOME is the user's home directory, and $PREFIX is node's configured node_prefix.

These are mostly for historic reasons. You are highly encouraged to place your dependencies locally in node_modules folders. They will be loaded faster, and more reliably.

I hope I answered, you just need to manage the paths to node_modules wherever you have kept it.

Comment: Hi Pavan, Thank you for your comment. Yes I want to keep them global. Would you be able to give me an example of it ?

Comment: So let's I installed jquery globally and this jquery folder is in the node_modules folder of  path user/local/appdata/. Now how would I use $ in the app.component.ts? Do I still need to import jquery in the file? If yes then what would be the path? @pavanjoshi

Comment: @techie   Firstly, you basically not need jQuery $ in an Angular file. 
If any other npm library if you need, you have to give complete path(.js) of your global node_modules in angular.json scripts, so it will be included throughout your app. Similar for any CSS libraries also. 
Still I say good to make these lib local to project and keep since versions of libraries better kept intact.